# Spring Data find by inner relation

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

My question is about the way Spring data is generating the query .

I have two entities  : Message , Sender

```
@Entity
public class Message extends BaseEntity {
 @ManyToOne
 protected Account sender;
}
```

I have a call to

```
messageDao.findBySenderId(Long id)
```

The result is query all columns from the two two table with a `left outer join` between the two tables , but my expectation was simply to just select from message table `where sender_id =` the passed value.

So is there a way to force selecting only the first message entity and not to join with the other one? I want simple condition in the where clause 
by using findBy not custom @Query

Answer (score 5):

You will need a repository like (untested) :

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
      Message findFirstBySenderId(Long id); 
}
```

See [repositories.query-methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods)

Comment: thanks but I already have the repository and as I mentioned I use a method call messageDao.findBySenderId(Long id) but is not behaving as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think Hibernate is doing a `LEFT JOIN` because your `@ManyToOne` is `optional = true` (default).

Try:

```
@ManyTone(optional = false)
```

And you will see Hibernate doing a query without a `JOIN`, as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch type LAZY for the associations types:
`@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`